# Creating View With Merged Row Values

Tags: mysql

Sorry if the subject wasn't too clear.  Here is the link to my sqlfiddle example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6806fa

I'm trying to have the role_list view only contain 1 row per store.  Basically what role_list should contain is the primary salesperson, agent, and manager employees.  So As you can see from the example sql query I ran for simply selecting all rows from role_list, it has a separate row for each A-Mart employee type (one row for primary salesperson, one row for agent, and one row for manager). Instead, I wanted it to just return 1 row for A-Mart, with the employee_id 100 for each position.

Specifically, the result output I'm trying to get is:

```
store_id   store_name   salesperson   agent   manager
----------|------------|-------------|-------|----------
1         |A-Mart      |100          |100    |100
2         |B-Mart      |102          |       |
3         |C-Mart      |103          |       |102
```

But instead, I am getting:

```
store_id   store_name   salesperson   agent   manager
----------|------------|-------------|-------|----------
1         |A-Mart      |100          |       |
1         |A-Mart      |             |100    |
1         |A-Mart      |             |       |100
2         |B-Mart      |102          |       |
3         |C-Mart      |             |       |102
3         |C-Mart      |103          |       |
```

I'm also trying to stick to only using joins instead of separate subquery select statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to do PIVOT, which can be achieved using `CASE`, `MAX` and `GROUP BY` in mysql.

```
SELECT
  s.store_id,
  s.store_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.role_char ='S' THEN emp.employee_id ELSE '' END )AS salesperson,
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.role_char ='A' THEN emp.employee_id ELSE '' END ) AS agent,
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.role_char ='M' THEN emp.employee_id ELSE '' END ) AS manager
FROM
  store s
  LEFT JOIN store_role sr ON sr.store_id=s.store_id AND sr.primary_f=1
  LEFT JOIN role r ON sr.role_id=r.role_id AND sr.store_id=r.store_id
  LEFT JOIN employee emp ON emp.employee_id = sr.employee_id 
GROUP BY s.store_id, s.store_name
```